# Enhance line quality

Tags: inkscape, vector, gimp, image-quality

I have the image in pic (black and white image) and I would like to increase the quality of the lines, which appear blurred. I tried to use the `erode` filter in `gimp`. The quality has improved a bit but not enough. Is there a way to improve the lines of a simple image like this and vectorize it using gimp or inkscape?

orgiginal image

[image]

After `erode` filter

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The original image isn't blurred. To be honest, I can't see anything that needs fixed.

Comment: Hello Billy, thank you for your answer. Maybe I just need to thicken the width of the lines and change all the gray pixels to black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the [G'MIC plugin](https://gmic.eu/) for GIMP, you can use the Lylejk's Stencil filter to thicken and darken lines.

Here's an example, showing the settings I used.

[image]

Note: I have no affiliation with the G'MIC website, or the plugin.

Comment: Hello Billy, thank you for your help. I've just tried and it works pretty fine. Is there any way to smooth it a bit and vectorize the image?

Comment: @Fly - GIMP isn't a vector image editor. It's a raster image editor.  It would be easier to simply redraw it using vector software, such as Inkscape, Illustrator, CorelDraw etc.